# How to localize pygtk & glade builtin widgets?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a problem. The scenario goes like this, I used pygtk builtin widgets including gtk-add, gtk-new and the rest in my apps. There widgets have their labels and all texts there are English. I do know how to localize python strings(say just create a .po file and prefix strings in python code with _()), but I've no idea how to localize these builtin widgets. I tried to add some entries in my .po files, say

```
    #my .po file
    msgid "_New"
    msgstr "_New in my language(_N)"
```

for the gtk-new widgetw in the hope that it would be helpful, but it didn't work. Could you guys help me with this? Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After reading in your PO file, you probably have to set the text of each of these widgets using [gtk-button-set-label](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-label)